# Changing Colour to Color in Java

Tags: java, colors

I'm working with a library that uses Colour, but I need the functionality of Color. Is there anything I can do to somehow "cast" or something, so that I will be able to use the methods of Color?

**--EDIT--**

Colour is `jxl.format.Colour`; Color is a `java.awt.Color`

Colour is an internal library class that offers limited functionality. I would like to perform slightly more advanced operations. For example:

- With Colour I can only assign a certain color:
  `Colour bgcol = Colour.BLUE;`
- Whereas Color givea me more options: `brighter()` and `darker()` methods, and so on.

My library forces me to use Colour, for instance: the method `setBackground(Colour)` is not applicable for the arguments (Color).

Comment: Ow... my brain. I think you need to explain more.

Comment: It's an enumeration class which contains the various colours available within the standard Excel colour palette

Comment: Unfortunately, [we still need more data here](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). Can you go into more detail about your exact needs and dependencies in your code?

Answer (score 4):

First - state what you are actually asking about. We can guess that your `Colour` is a `jxl.format.Colour` and your `Color` is a `java.awt.Color`, but its a guess.

If that is correct, the Colour enum has a `getRGB()` method which returns the red, green and blue components of the colour (I'm English, I spell colour that way naturally). The `java.awt.Color` class has a constructor that accepts these components.

You can therefore do:

```
public static Color convert(Colour col) {
    return new Color(
        col.getDefaultRGB().getRed(),
        col.getDefaultRGB().getGreen(),
        col.getDefaultRGB().getBlue() );
}
```

To save creating new `Color` instances all the time, you could store the translations in an EnumMap.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for. However, `col.getRGB()` gives `The method getRGB() is undefined for the type Colour`. Also, I could explicitly state the RGB values, if that would be easier.

Comment: +1 for psychic, Google-mediated debugging before the OP mentioned these specifically. Good catch! :)

Comment: @Hurdler : Apologies - I was zipping between Google results and forgot the precise name of the API.

Comment: Hmm, Eclipse still suggests adding a cast, but it might be just me

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you're trying to cast all representations of the name `Colour` to `Color`. You haven't specified if a find-and-replace for your library files may be most appropriate, so let's assume that you're trying to define a generic interface to perform this fixup. Nor have you specified any other need in your code, other than the desire to glue these two together. Do you want to shim one into a class of the other to satisfy some library or code dependency you may be having? It's difficult to tell.

Because [classes aren't first-class objects in Java,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996280/why-arent-classes-first-class-objects-in-java) we could do this by defining a set of interfaces or subclasses for each instance of `Colour` that you want to replace with `Color`. *Or,* we could do some crazy things with [Java reflection.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

These are, of course, hacks incumbent to a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) you've expressed: trying to iteratively fix up the interface names for each of your classes is *much harder* than defining an IDE rule or modification in your existing code to interface with each class named `Colour`. So, I would actually recommend the latter over attempts to work around the issue by abusing Java language features beyond their intended scope.

**Edit:** With more information from the OP, this is a desire for [interface-stapling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern). I'll leave the rest to other answers.